# Bind a java swing gui and c++ backend for a standalone application, which form two different projects

Tags: java, c++, swing, java-native-interface

I want to bind a **JAVA Swing GUI** with **C++** back end for a standalone application. These two form two different projects. I've read about **Java Native** Interface. Though JNI appears to be the best solution for this, I have few questions regarding JNI:

1. Can JNI help me bind different projects (one in Java swing and other
   in c++)?
2. If yes, how will it be different from binding with the files in the same project?

Being a newbie in JNI, a detail technical help will helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if the intent of this project is to bind Java and C++ through JNI. Seems more like you have to create an application in C++ that will provide services through the network and you will consume them using Java (probably sockets), thus no JNI involved.

Comment: I did not get what you mean by "through the network" and "Java(sockets)'? Will you please elaborate?

Comment: Uh... a C++ application that exposes a service through a port and a defined communication protocol, then in your client application (Java or whatever) you connect to this service by using a socket and send streams of data using this communication protocol, and JNI is not involved at all. Looks like you're new to networking or probably that's not part of your work. What's your specific requirement or work to do?

Comment: I am not familiar with networking at all. The c++ back end code is already in use. Users use it through command line. I have to develop a GUI for this C++ back end, in Java swing.

Comment: Is this a homework or project from college or did you receive this project from work?

Comment: I received it from work

Comment: Then it would be better to ask to your colleagues or somebody else about how are they consuming this backend services. And I'm not talking in end-user terms (command line or w/e tool they're using) but how these tools to consume these services work. Then you may have an idea of how to implement your solution.

Comment: The users have the entire c++ code on their machines (note that users are internal organization users) and they use command line statements to use the functionality.

Comment: Isn't any other software engineer or fellow programmer there? Are you the only person that has to bring support to this system?

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply. I will ask my colleagues and try to get some help.

Comment: We do have senior programmers. But initially my doubt appeared silly and didn't wanted to consult the seniors for this. But, since you fell that the requirements should be more clear, I will go for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes .

JNI helps us perform calls to our own C++ library from java.

I'm guessing you are planning for the GUI and C++ to be on the same process (if yes JNI is the answer, if no, you will have to resort to intra-process communication).

2. You will have to bind dynamically projects from different languages.

Java is managed memory, meaning you have no true ownership over memory (The allmighty GC decides if he will delete or not something).

C++ is unmanaged memory, meaning you will have to pick up your own garbage.

With this difference being said, it's quite obvious that when interacting with eachother you need to be sure not to delete memory allocated in one from another.

This is one of the differences that you will bump into from binding files within the same project.

The other one is that you will resort to Dynamic linking.

The code frome Java is compiled into intermediate while the one from C++ is compiled into CPU specific assembler. Meaning you cannot use code from one into the other.

Hence we resort to Dynamic Linking.

The C++ code will be compiled into a shared library (.so or .dll depending on platform). At runtime, your java Swing application (which will be the entry point) will load the dynamic library into the program's memory (you will need to call this manually from your code, System.loadLibrary is the function if I remember correctly).

Once the library is loaded, if you built your library properly (for this you need to follow tutorials, I'm not going to explain that here), you will have the .dll exported symbols available in java .

The usual practice when using JNI is to create a bridge library that links a number of C++ functions to a bridge class in Java.

There are automatic programs that creates this bridge for you (such as SWIG), but I strongly recommend you avoid them (especially since you don't have a full grasp of JNI).